# Toggle table row based on if condition not working

Tags: html, angular

Need to toggle one table row based on if condition not working.

If status id none I need to open a form in popup but if status is done popup shouldn't open.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let person of personList | 
        searchFilter:searchValue;index as i">
    <tr *ngIf="person.status == 'none'" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#personModal" 
            (click)="function(person.id)">
        <tr *ngIf="person.status == 'done'" >
            <td>Place</td>
            <td>Job</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

When I tried this solution the row is not displaying in the table list

Comment: It may help to add the typescript component class, so that anyone offering help can use the variables you are using, and it will be easy for them.

Comment: it is just an html, angular think i guess nothing related to script. there  is some issue while am using two tr tag for one table row!

Comment: You are not closing the second `<tr>` tag, is it a typo?

Comment: what i find is you do not close second `<tr>` after second `</td>`

Comment: There should be one tr at a time based on the condition, one opening  and closing tr (one row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should do something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let person of personList | searchFilter:searchValue;index as i">
  <tr *ngIf="person.status == 'none'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#personModal" 
      (click)="someFunction(person.id)">
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Job</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="person.status == 'done'" >
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Job</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

But it's important to see your TypeScript code. You should make a Stackblitz example.

Comment: let me check and will get back, Thank you!